# How to install devtoolset-11 on Centos 8 Stream

Tags: centos, devtoolset

I'd like to use devtoolset-11 on Centos Stream 8, but can't find any information on whether the Software Collection repositories are available for Centos Stream. The usual dnf install centos-release-scl doesn't work which previously for Centos 7 would have enabled the Software Collections repos which provides the devtoolsets. How can I install devtoolset-11 on Centos Stream?

Answer (score 3):

To use recent versions of compilers such as gcc 11 on centos stream, install the gcc toolsets, eg gcc-toolset-11 which is in the AppStream repos.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! On Rocky Linux 8 it helped me to lookup names of available package names with `dnf list gcc-toolset-*-toolchain` and installed it like this `dnf install gcc-toolset-10-toolchain`